# Can't identify DIV id?

Tags: javascript, html

This is small piece of code of my project. Well here just I'm fetching id of table's 1st row elements but there is something mistake of fetching id of div and select tag ? Any one can help me please ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function add(tableID) {        
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);         
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            alert("cell length "+colCount);

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                alert(table.rows[0].cells[i].childNodes[0].id);
            }               
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" id="dataTable" >
      <tr>
        <td><INPUT type="checkbox" id="cb" name="chk[]" disabled="true"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txt" name="t" size="3" maxlength="3" readonly="true" value="1"></td>
        <td>
          <select  id='slct'>
            <option value='-1' selected>- - - - - Select - - - - -</option>
            <option value="0">xyz</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>                
          <div id="div">qwerty</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>

    <button onclick="add('dataTable')">show</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any characters between tags, even whitespace, are HTML text nodes (multiple non-tag characters in a row are all combined into one node). This means the first (and last) child node for the third and fourth TD are both text nodes (with only whitespace).

```
table.rows[0].cells[0].childNodes.length === 1
table.rows[0].cells[1].childNodes.length === 1
table.rows[0].cells[2].childNodes.length === 3
table.rows[0].cells[3].childNodes.length === 3
```

If you modified your HTML to this...

```
<td><select  id='slct'>
    <option value='-1' selected>- - - - - Select - - - - -</option>
    <option value="0">xyz</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><div id="div">qwerty</div></td>
```

you would get your expected behavior from your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is simple as is the method to troubleshoot.

Try logging the childNodes to console:

```
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    console.log(table.rows[0].cells[i].childNodes);
}
```

You will see that the first childNode in each cell is a textNode. This is from the line break in source.

Use `children` instead to exclude the textNodes

```
for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {        
    console.log(table.rows[0].cells[i].children[0].id);
 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQbcGwArUOpWRr6fQWGv)**</kbd>